# How to pass multidimentional array to $this->data?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
Controller:

    $sid = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $serial = $this->contract_items->get_all_serial($id);
    $_items = array();
        foreach ($serial as $k => $v) {
            $oldserial =  $this->contract_items->get_childrens($sid);
            $_items[$v->contract_id] = array("children" => $oldserial);
        }
    $this->data['serial_items'] = $_items;
    $this->build_view("contracts/serial.php");
```

this is the output  of this when i print_r() and i want this to print the "FDO1643R26G"
and "FDO1643R26G" in my view.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [serial_num] => FDO1643R26G-XXX ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [serial_num] => FDO1643R26G-XXX-XXX ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in data in an associative array to views from controllers. In your case, just assign your array to a key in an array, and pass it along:

```
$data['_items'] = $_items;

$this->load->view('my_view', $data);

// in the view, you can access the array
// in $_items
```